# Where can I find people willing to pay me in bitcoin for services?

Tags: bitcoin-economy, services

For those of us unable or unwilling to spend our native currencies on bitcoin, but willing to work for them. Where are the bitcoin-jobs(or micro-jobs) to be found?

Answer (score 6):

[CoinWorker](http://coinworker.com/) pays Bitcoins for repetitive jobs such as identifying images that contain adult content, or rating search engine results.  It acts as a Bitcoin interface to the [CrowdFlower](http://crowdflower.com/) network.

Answer (score 3):

You might try [bitcoinLocator](http://www.bitcoinlocator.com). You can advertise services that you provide in your area, and people can message you privately.

You can also try posting on the [bitcoin forums services board](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=52.0)

Comment: In bitcoinlocator there are currencly 13 offers (combining buy+sell) in the whole world.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the suggestions. Best to meet people that pay a decent wage....don't work for  pennys....make a website and offer your service. But don't work for nickel and dimes...hold to your integrity. If they want workers for a penny a day i am sure they will find them and a lot of them....there is hell ..stay out of hell.
Google sites have free websites.http://www.google.com/services/ Then you can offer you service or grow your service.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I'd say the best place to do this is the Marketplace forum of bitcointalk: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=5.0 - be forewarned that to use this forum, you need to have created a bitcointalk account, post five posts in the newbie forum, and stay logged in for four hours.  Until then, you're stuck in the Newbie forum.

But after that, there are a lot of people offering services on that site, so if you want to join them, feel free.  A hint to make those four hours go by faster: you need to be logged into the forum and on your computer, but you don't need to be actively browsing the forum that whole time.

If you're just talking about a one off jobs, this is probably your best bet.  If you want to actually build something that appeals to a large amount of people in the bitcoin community, you might want to crowd fund it using Bitcoinstarter: https://bitcoinstarter.com/

Answer (score 1):

I tried out [bitcoinget.com](http://bit.ly/1c9zR8o). I've been paying visit to them regularly for 3 days, and I have been paid everyday (around 10PM EST). One of those days I have earned $6 worth of bitcoins(0.0056 BTC) in few hours. $6 might not sound like a lot, but considering many websites pretty much refuse to pay you your earning until certain threshold, them actually paying over a $1 worth of payment daily is a huge plus.

In terms of Microworking for bitcoins, I think bitcoinget.com offers easiest tasks(not some bs tasks that makes you run around jumping hoops) for quite a bit of payment for single tasks. (16-24 uBTC for 20sec tasks, sometimes I've seen--still seeing--tasks that are super easy but pays around 90-120 uBTC per task.)

If you are interested in Microworking for straightforward USD, and has very low payout,
Try out Amazon Mechanical Turk. Minimum payout is $1, and it is owned by amazon. It really pays.

I've wrote a income report from both bitcoinget.com and Amazon Mturk on my blog, [you can checkout payment proofs here](http://jinslist.net/microworking-and-bitcoins/).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is [ForBitcoin.com](http://forbitcoin.com/).

Comment: really? The site seems kind of stagnant to me.

Comment: @lathomas64 have you offered your services there?

Comment: Maybe #bitcoin-otc as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job:

- Elance, Freelancer, oDesk, Zaarly, Taskrabbit, Peddl, Craiglist, eBay, etc.

Then exchange those proceeds into bitcoins.

At some point those might offer bitcoins for cashout, particularly those with an international worker base.  But for now, take the (relatively) higher rates paid by these sites and do the conversion to bitcoin yourself.

Also read:

- https://www.ogrr.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1424

Answer (score 0):

You can try these sites:

- http://www.bitcoinjobs.com/
- http://bittask.com/
- http://bitgigs.com/

...

Answer (score 0):

There are two Reddits that are good for this:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/Jobs4Bitcoins/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/Jobs4Litecoins/

Answer (score 0):

Although it hasn't launched yet, eventually http://codeforbitcoins.com will allow for posting and working on programming jobs for bitcoins

Answer (score -1):

Best Place less fee and secure is, http://iwill4coin.com  its  growing rapidly, post your jobs/services there and get paid with bitcoin, no other payments accepted..